# SOAP API: Populate lookup using an external Id

Tags: soap-api, lookup, externalid

Helping a client structure their C# SOAP API an upsert into Salesforce and we're running into issues.

I'm having a hard time finding documentation on this.
(searched all this doc, found nothing regarding it https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_guidelines_platform_connect.htm )

How are we able to populate a lookup field on a given object using the External Id from the parent Object ... via the SOAP API?

Code:

```
query = new SalesforcePartnerClient_V46.QueryBuilder(SalesforcePartnerClient_V46.QueryBuilder.ActionType.Upsert, "Child_Object__c");

//Child object looks up to parent object via Parent__c

query.AddColumn("Parent__r", "{'Parent_ExternalId__c':" + row["ExternalId"].ToString() + "}");
query.AddColumn("Admin__c", Boolean.TrueString);
```